# Add multiple columns prominent of the same operation to pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, optimization

### The question

Let's say I had a DataFrame `df` with a numeric column `x` and a categorical column `y`. I want to calculate the `q` and the `quantile of q` in which the `quantile of q` is higher than `0` for each group of `y`. With these two values, `q` and `quantile of q`, I want to calculate the number of elements lower than `quantile of q`. To do this, I start with `q=0` and I keep increasing `q` in `0.05` until `quantile of q` is greater than `0`.

### The solution

```py
groups = df.groupby(y_col)

less_quantile = np.empty(len(groups))
quantiles = np.empty(len(groups))
qs = np.empty(len(groups))

for i, (_, group) in zip(range(len(groups)), groups):
    q = 0.0
    while q <= 1.0:
        quantile = group[x_col].quantile(q)
        if quantile > 0.0:
            less_quantile[i] = (group[x_col] < quantile).sum() #count Trues
            qs[i] = q
            quantiles[i] = quantile
            break
        q += 0.05

df_final = df.drop_duplicates(y_col)\
             .assign(quantile=quantiles, q=qs, less_quantile_count=less_quantile)
```

### The problem

There are the following problems regarding the implementation above:

- I'm not using any pandas or numpy optimizations (e.g. vectorization).
- It's not guaranteed by pandas that `drop_duplicates` and `groupby` will have the same order of groups to assign it the way I did. The only reason I did this was that by experimentation they were the same.

#### What are my other options?

1. Using `agg` or `apply` and `merge`
2. Creating empty columns to calculate and to replicate qs, then quantiles, and then counting the ones less than quantile

#### What other problems can it cause?

1. I'll probably need to recalculate quantile lots of times.
2. I'll occupy lots of memory with repeated values within each row of each group.

### Why do I care for that?

As a C programmer, it hurts a lot to use so much memory unnecessarily and the same for the operations. Also because it is a small DataFrame I can solve it easily, but if the DataFrame was too big, I should know the best way to do this. I'm not sure if it is a limitation of the library due to its abstraction level or if I don't know enough to solve the problem the way it has to be.

### Edit 1 - Added an example

```py
x          y
0    pear  0.0
1    pear  0.0
2    pear  0.194329
3   apple  0.714319
4   apple  0.171905
5   apple  0.337234
6   apple  0.769216
7  orange  0.529154
8  orange  0.844691

# Let's take pear as an example:
quantile = group_pear.quantile(0) # 0.0
quantile = group_pear.quantile(0.05) # 0.0
...
quantile = group_pear.quantile(0.50) # 0.0
quantile = group_pear.quantile(0.55) # 0.09857
q = 0.55

# Found quantile of q with q=0.55 resulting in 0.09857
# Now I just need to count how many rows within the pear group have 'y' 
# less than 0.09857
count_pear = (group_pear['y'] < 0.09857).sum()

# I just need to do the same for other groups and then produce a 
# DataFrame like this
x            q     quantile  count_less
0    pear    0.55  0.09857   2
1    apple   0.0   ...       ...
2    orange  0.0   ...       ...
```

Comment: Can you provide some example data?

Comment: @mcsoini added!

Comment: Few different approaches you could take here. First, you can compute count_less without knowing the quantile value, by counting how many values are zero or below. Using that variable, you could find the minimum quantile which produces a greater than zero value. That only requires a single call to quantile. Second approach would be to try every quantile at once - quantile accepts an array, so you can get all quantile values at once. Since the slowest part of computing quantile is sorting the array, and it avoids doing this multiple times, this will be faster.